# How to increase speed of getting datas from webserver for android app

Tags: java, android, webserver

I'm designing a android application that has client and server side. The main database is in server which every android device db is trying to look like. Whenever Android device is online, the app syncs with server database(the main database). Because I can change the datas with adding, deleting or updating in the database in server(Users can't change database in Android device, a.k.a Sqlite db). After synchronization, the Sqlite db will be added, deleted or updated.

There are a lot of images in server database, and I'm sending all of data as json type from PHP.

```
$datas = array('cats' => $cats, 'news' => $news, 'products' => $products);
$datas_json = (object) array('datas' => $datas);
$json = json_encode($datas_json);
echo $json;
```

And the app reads with BufferReader.

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
```

And afterwards, I'm trying to get all data is coming from server as string. There is a real problem about speed.

```
public String parseFromBuffer(BufferedReader rd) throws IOException
{
    String line = "";
    String full = "";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        full += line;
    }
    return full;
}
```

Because, If you think just one image may have 100.000 characters(in PHP side, I'm using base64 for images to send java and I'm decoding in java again.), imagine 1000 images! So, sometimes it  takes 1-2 min to get 4-5 images with this way. After getting '`full`' string(it could have 1.000.000 character!), I use jsonParser to get datas.

```
public jsonParser(String json_string) throws JSONException
{
    json = new JSONObject(json_string);
}
...
public void parseJson() throws JSONException
{
    JSONObject datas = json.getJSONObject("datas");

JSONArray cats = datas.getJSONArray("cats");
for(int i = 0; i < cats.length(); i++)
{
    JSONObject c = cats.getJSONObject(i);

    cat_id.add(c.getInt("cat_id"));
    cat_name_tr.add(c.getString("cat_name_tr"));
    cat_name_eng.add(c.getString("cat_name_eng"));
    cat_upper_id.add(c.getInt("cat_upper_id"));
    cat_order.add(c.getInt("cat_order"));
}
...
```

And finally, I insert, update or delete data which comes from `jsonParser()` to sqlite db.

In short, I have a problem or I need solution about speed of getting images across server-client and also  in `parseFromBuffer()` method. You can suggest any advice, you can criticize of my way of doing this, may be I should serialize something, may be I should download all images in server to 'res' folder somehow...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `full += line;` hurts bad. Use a `StringBuilder` instead!

Comment: I used StringBuilder and it is 5 or 6 times faster than before. Thank you.

Comment: You can speed it up even more if you use the `StringBuilder` constructor that takes the `int capacity` parameter (with the expected length of the string as the argument).

Comment: To convert a `StringBuilder` to `String`, you can simply use the `toString()` method.